# Using outlet Collection to check if all segmented controls have been selected

Tags: iphone, ios, iboutletcollection

I am new to outlet collections but believe that it is what I need for what I am trying to do. Basically I have a lot of segmented controls that I would like to check if they have all been selected before continuing. For a single check I know I can do

```
    int selectedSegment = segment.selectedSegmentIndex;
    if (selectedSegment == -1 )
{
    //do stuff/alert
}
```

but how do I do it with a collection of them? I have set my IBOutletCollection to:

```
IBOutletCollection(UISegmentedControl) NSArray *allSegmentControlOutlet;
```

Im just not sure how to roll through them checking to make sure each one has something selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (UISegmentedControl *control in allSegmentControlOutlet)
{
    if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == -1 )
    {
        //do stuff/alert
    }
}
```

Comment: oh nice this works perfectly! Now is there a good way to tie a label to each of those segmented controls and say, turn it red if it the selected segment was ==-1?

Comment: Well you have full access to the `control` in the loop, so if you hit your condition you could replace `//do stuff/alert` with something like like `[control setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];` (Set `control .segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;` for `tintColor` to work).